# Can I scrape a html page which is local machine using scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am new to scrapy. I need to make a small demo using scrapy.

I used scrapy for scraping stackoverflow and I was successfull. I want to try to this on html page which is stored in my local machine. Is it possible?

Please help me out

Comment: As far as I'm aware, scrappy does not support scraping from your filesystem. I imagine the reason being that there is no logical reason why you'd use it for local files. However you could do that with a local server, serving the files. In other words you could go to the directory where your html files are stored(I imagine static html the way you described it) and do `python -m "SimpleHTTPServer"`. This will fire up a local http server by default on port 8000. In other words, all the html files and data in that directory will be served on `http://localhost:8000`

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can. Just keep the allowed domain to blank and in the start_url, put the location of the html file as `file://home/file.html`.
The code will be something like this

```
class MySpider(Spider):
    name = "myspider"
    allowed_domains = []
    start_urls = ["file:///home/file.html"]
```